# Example where the associated sheaf does not exist

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, sheaf-theory, adjoint-functors

What is a simple example of a topological space $X$ and a complete category $\mathcal{C}$ such that the inclusion $\mathbf{Sh}(X,\mathcal{C}) \hookrightarrow \mathbf{PSh}(X,\mathcal{C})$ has no left adjoint, i.e. there is a  $\mathcal{C}$-valued presheaf on $X$ which does not have an [associated sheaf](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheafification)?

A sufficient condition for the existence of the associated sheaf is explained in Section 17.4 in [*Categories and sheaves*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-27950-4) by Kashiwara-Schapira: here the category $\mathcal{C}$ is assumed be be complete, cocomplete, filtered colimits are exact, and the [IPC property](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/IPC-property) holds. So for a counterexample one of these properties must fail.

Comment: I suppose you are using the limit sketch definition of sheaf. If $\mathcal{C}$ is locally presentable then you get a left adjoint using e.g. a small object argument. This further narrows the possibilities for a counterexample.

Comment: Indeed, and I think $\mathcal{C}=\mathbf{Top}$ will be a counterexample. But I don't have anything specific so far.

Comment: I'm not so sure. What goes wrong with the obvious approach of taking the sheafification of the underlying presheaf of sets and then putting some suitable topology on each set of sections? There is an adjoint lifting theorem for topological concrete categories that can sometimes be used in these situations.

Comment: @ZhenLin There are two approaches to the associated sheaf of sets: $F^a(U) = \{s \in \prod_{x \in U}F_x : s \text{ locally consistent}\}$ and $F^a=F^{++}$ where $F^+(U) = \mathrm{colim}_{W \text{ covering of } U}H^0(F,W)$. If $F$ takes values in $\mathbf{Top}$, in the 1st approach we would probably take the subspace topology of the product of the stalks (which are spaces). But the problem is here the universal property, since we need to verify continuity on a limit. The problem with the 2nd approach is that we have a colimit, and the sheaf condition is not clear since $\mathbf{Top}$ lacks IPC.